# How can I model this smoking pipe?

Tags: modeling

I've tried a bunch of times, but I can't get it done right. Any tips?
This is the pipe:[image: This is the pipe]
<sub>(source: [klatmagazine.com](http://www.klatmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Klat_Radica_Chic_Giulio_Iacchetti_02.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Welcome tot he site. The tutorial about [cup modeling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y__uzGKmxt8) should point you into right direction as it's essentially the same, just the handle is not a handle and is longer. Also it could help if you show what you tried as it could show what do you have problems with.

Comment: @matteoRepetto Did you manage to make it or do you still want some help?

Comment: Hi! I actually managed to model it really well thanks to the tutorial. I was really busy I'm the last two days and I had no time to reply. Thanks for the help! I'll upload aN image of the final result soon , right now I'm trying to fix my pc. Thank you again for the help.